# C++ including linux/types.h for size_t

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to create a C++ wrapper (adding object orientation) around a C library (of which I am the author, i.e. I can apply changes there if needed). The C library defines some structs that make use of `size_t` as defined in `linux/types.h` since it interfaces with the kernel.

I am now trying to include the header of the C library (that defines the struct) in the sources of my attempt at a C++ library. However, if I do so, the compiler tells me that

> `size_t` does not name a type

What is the correct way to get access to `size_t` from `linux/types.h` in `C++`?

P.S.: The header file contains a `#ifdef _cplusplus extern "C" { #endif` block

Comment: `size_t` is a C standard type, not a Linux kernel type.

Comment: @Olaf: Maybe I formulated my question to brief: I have a library that interfaces to a kernel driver via `ioctl`. The driver copies some data between the userspace and the kernelspace. And as it happens, for the kernelside you will find `size_t` where I describe. I tried to include that, since I wanted to make sure size_t has the same definition on the driver and the userlibrary side.

Comment: Why do you need kernel headers to use `ioctl`? The userspace C library provides `ioctl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include kernel headers in userspace.

As stated in the C and C++ standards, `size_t` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and for C++, `<cstddef>` defines `std::size_t`).

Comment: The reason I did this was that the library uses `ioctl` to pass data to and from the kernel. Is there any garantee that `size_t(stddef.h)` can hold `size_t(linux/types.h)`?

Comment: Since `size_t` is supposed to be defined as the type returned by a `sizeof` expression it would not be very good if they weren't the same type, or at least the same width.

Comment: Is there any good explanation *why* I should not include kernel headers in user space (for the case where userspace provides an interface to kernelspace)?

Comment: Because it breaks encapsulation, and it's easier to cause problems if you interface directly with the kernel. If you're talking directly to the kernel then maybe your library isn't userspace ... but if you just need `ioctl` then you don't need to talk directly to the kernel. If userspace provides an interface then you should use that interface, e.g. the C library provides a wrapper for `ioctl` in `<sys/ioctl.h>` so you don't need to use the system call. Why not use that?

Comment: [The use of kernel headers in user space has long been discouraged. The kernel headers are not written with user space in mind, and they can change at any time. The proper way for user-space applications to interface with the kernel is by way of the C library, which provides its own structures and, when necessary, translates them into whatever the current kernel expects. This separation helps to keep user-space programs from breaking when the kernel changes.](https://lwn.net/Articles/113349/) That was in 2004, and it had "long been discouraged" even then.

Comment: I will give the article a read and am now slightly englihtened, and also between a rock an a hardplace: I have one header that is shared between the driver and the userspace with the ioctl numbers and the data structures used by the kernel and the userspace. So do I use the userspace headers there as well? How about `dma_addr_t`? Thanks for all the additional information.

Comment: I have read through the info, and think I can clarify my point further: I have written a driver and a userspace library to interface it. Since both have to use the same ioctl numbers, I thought it natural to create a header for the ioctl's that is used for both, the kernel and the userspace application. The header also includes struct definitions, for the structs that the ioctl's can return to userspace. Again these structs now appear on the kernel side (driver) and in userspace (the library). So which headers are correct?

Comment: Finally, I think the [(only) comment](https://lwn.net/Articles/114207/) under the article sums it up nicely: The C library is a userspace program as well, and somewhere we need to use the same headers. I see my "program" (pairing of driver and userspace library) in the same spot as the c library, since it is not a pure program that uses libraries to interface to the kernel, but a driver and the userspace library to access it. On a side note: the technique worked fine for C, however it broke when I tried to create a C++ library on top of the C library.

Answer (score 1):

```
Defined in header <cstddef>
Defined in header <cstdio>
Defined in header <cstring>
Defined in header <ctime>
Defined in header <cstdlib> (since C++11)
Defined in header <cwchar> (since C++11)
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t

Comment: Although it is only guaranteed to be defined in the `std` namespace in those headers.