# Why not to include linux headers in userspace

Tags: linux, header-files

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36479521/258418) I was repeatedly told not to include kernel header in userspace.

I would like to know why/how? (Keeping in mind that we are talking about a userlibrary to [interface a device driver](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders)).
There must be a reason that `make headers_install` exists and all linux distros I am aware of have kernel header packages. And how else would I define the IOCTL numbers, if not using the makros provided for that?

So why should I avoid including kernel headers in userpsace?